# How to send valid json reponse to android through webservice in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, web-services

I have created webservice in angularjs for android application.
Here is the link http://projects.developmentshowcase.com/fajr/#/login?vEmail=user@abc.com&vPassword=password.

> When I try to parse this into http://jsonlint.com/ to validate json

[image]

> **I got this result**

[image]

> I want to provide them (android) only JSON result. Like beollow screeshot

[image]
**These are my scripts :**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fajr App</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/data.js"></script>
    <script src="app/directives.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularFileUpload']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                title: 'login',
                templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            .when('/fblogin', {
                title: 'login',
                templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            ;
}])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data, $templateCache) {
        $rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function () {
            $templateCache.removeAll();
        });
    });


app.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', 'Data', '$location', '$window', function ($scope, Data, $location, $window) {
    if ($location.search().vFacebookID) {
        Data.get('authentication.php?vEmail=' + $location.search().vEmail + '&vFacebookID=' + $location.search().vFacebookID + '&vDeviceType=' + $location.search().vDeviceType + '&vDeviceToken=' + $location.search().vDeviceToken).then(function (results) {
            $scope.result = results;
        });
    } else {
        Data.get('authentication.php?vEmail=' + $location.search().vEmail + '&vPassword=' + $location.search().vPassword).then(function (results) {
            $scope.result = results;
        });
    }
}]);
```

**dashboard.html**

```
{{result}}
```

Comment: in your 2nd screen shot it should be like `<div ng-app="myApp">
        <div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
    </div>` in your second screen shot there is not space between attributes like `<div data-ng-view=""id="ng-view"class="slide-animation"></div>` without any space

Comment: @pankajparkar : I have posted screen shot as I get result in the browser, I have provided link in question. You also can check in jsonlint and check if the link has valid json or not.

Comment: did you enabled CORS on server side